# Git - Unable to push, unable to pull after commit

Tags: git, version-control, branch, pull, git-pull

I was on the way to commit and push changes.
The changes were committed successfully.
Then, I was trying to push and it failed.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin mpgf:mpgf
Pushing to https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX

To https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX
 ! [rejected]        mpgf -> mpgf (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXXXXXXXX'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')

hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then, I was tried to pull (now I see there were some changes), and it failed:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --no-commit origin mpgf
You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).

Please, commit your changes before you can merge.

Completed with errors, see above.
```

What was the reason it happened and what are my steps to push my changes carefully?

P.S. Now I see there are several changes that I have to pull and there is 1 change that I have to push.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new branch that will track the remote branch you want to pull ( with "git  branch --track").Then  pull the changes from the remote. Afterwards checkout on your original branch and merge the new branch into it. Now your remote and local branches are equal and you can push.